# Convert key/value array

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to convert to following array. Do I need to map over it or is there some other way with Object.values etc:

```
[
  {
    key: "eyeColor",
    value: "Blue/Green",
   },
   {
     key: "eyeColor",
     value: "Blue",
   },
   {
     key: "hairColor",
     value: "black",
   }
];
```

into:

```
{
  hairColor: ["Blond", "Brown"],
  eyeColor: ["Blue"],
}
```

Comment: `.reduce` is your friend here.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `key` is the key properties and the `value` is the corresponding grouped-value properties.
- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate over the above pairs and convert to objects:

```js
const data = [ { key: "eyeColor", value: "Blue/Green" }, { key: "eyeColor", value: "Blue" }, { key: "hairColor", value: "black" } ];

const groupedPairs = [...data.reduce((map, { key, value }) =>  map.set(key, [...(map.get(key) ?? []), value]), new Map)];

const list = groupedPairs.map(([ prop, list ]) => ({ [prop]: list }))

console.log(list);
```

**EDIT AFTER CHANGE OF EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```js
const data = [ { key: "eyeColor", value: "Blue/Green" }, { key: "eyeColor", value: "Blue" }, { key: "hairColor", value: "black" } ];

const res = data.reduce((acc, { key, value }) => ({
  ...acc, [key]: [...(acc[key] ?? []), value]
}), {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: How do I make the return type in my TypeScript {[k: string]: string[]} not {[x: number]: any;}[]

Comment: @ComCool try ``new Map<string, string[]>()`` instead of ``new Map``

Comment: Type '{ [x: string]: string[]; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ [k: string]: string[]; }'.

Comment: @ComCool Can you share a sandbox link and explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ComCool the pen is not showing the right code

Comment: Dammit, here you go: https://jsitor.com/HdEfxJsWw

Comment: @ComCool the function returns an array of ``IUserFilters.userFilters``, so the type should be ``userFilters?: { [k: string]: string[]; }[]``

Comment: My bad. The function needs to return a objects with arrays inside like this:
{hairColor: ["Blond", "Brown"]},{eyeColor: ["Blue"]}

Comment: @ComCool the current solution provides such output.

Comment: Current function returns this [{eyeColor: ["Blue/Green","Blue"]},{"hairColor": ["black"]}]

Comment: Which is the expected output you mentioned above, please elaborate

Comment: You're expected output is irrelevant to the sample input, do you mean you want the final result to be one object instead of list of objects?

Comment: Yes, one object with arrays inside.

Comment: @ComCool I updated the answer with the new solution.